# Tizen TV Emulator Not Launching (HAXM not Detected)

Tags: tizen, haxm, smart-tv, macos-big-sur, tizen-emulator

Emulator Manager cannot launch the TV emulator (platform: tv-samsung-5.5-x86) on my Mac, getting the error message:

Failed to launch emulator: T-samsung-5.5-x86

Your system cannot support HW virtualization.
Try install KVM (ubuntu) or HAX (windows or Mac)

The emulator was working before on this computer.

I updated the packages via Package Manager. HAXM was also installed. Recently, I had ugraded to macOS BigSur (Version 11.0.1)

Has enyone encountered the same issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You can go to https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/how-use-tizen-studio-on-ubuntu-18.04 to find answer.

After installing kvm or hax, please try to execute the following script:

`$ sudo adduser $USER kvm`

**Note:**
To apply this change, you must restart or logout/login.